How do I convert a char to char[] in c++?
What is going on? I just want to convert the char in a list with one element. I would expect s to be "t", but it gives a weird output.
int main(){
  char c = 'z';
  char s[] = {c};

  printf("End: %c, %s", c, s);
}

output: End: z, zz♀ a

You should not use s[] in C++ anymore that is a leftover from C++ (that has no array size it is just bugs waiting to happen), use std::string. Same is kind of true for printf, use std::format (C++20) and std::cout, or std::print (C++23). Anyway what's happening is printf will look for a 0 in the string (to indicate its end) and it is not finding one (your program is incorrect)

When you use char s[] = {c};, then s will be an array of 1 element, lacking the zero termination requires to print with "%s".

In C++ you would not use printf (your broken code is pure C). Anyway this problem sufferers from XY problem, why do you need to do this? I'm sure there are better ways to do it then doing this conversion.

These few lines of code tell me you are not learning C++ from a good (up-to-date) source. Some good resources to learn C++ from are learncpp.com for your initial steps (it is very decent for an online tutorial).
Then use cppreference to lookup everything C++ has to offer.
And finally use the C++ core guidelines to keep up to date with how C++ evolves and how it is supposed to be used.

Use std::array instead of c-style arrays. Or std::string and std::cout

The C-style %s expects a null-terminated C-style character array string.  Your character array is not null-terminated, so it does not comply with the requirements of %s.

Also, the code you provided already does successfully convert a char to a char[].  Your printf is incorrect.  It should be printf("End: %c, %c\n", c, c[0]); ... since your char array is not a C-style string.

Alternatively, you can avoid needing the null-terminator if you tell printf explicitly how large s really is, eg: printf("End: %c, %.1s", c, s); or printf("End: %c, %.*s", c, 1, s);
